# How to create the changeable color scheme for a website?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

How to create the changeable color scheme for a website?

I even do not know how to start to do it.
I know only, that I should use sass.

Could you give some links to tutorials?

ex:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCGc2.png)

Comment: `I know only, that I should use sass` not really, you could use SASS, you could use LESS, you could even use CSS, you could even go the javascript route.  SASS / LESS, are just pre-processors, for CSS.  I would first suggest you learn about CSS selectors, the trick here is to learn about the `Cascading` aspect of what CSS stands for.  Then doing a color scheme is very easy.

Comment: Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: How can I solve something if I do not know how to do it? I can not find tutorials, that is why asked question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in many different ways. First ones that come into mind are:

#### In plain CSS

You can set a general CSS class on your `body` tag and based on that load a custom color CSS file. You have to use the [custom CSS properties](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables). Beware of browser support though. The idea is to use variables instead of plain color codes, and color the elements using you custom color palette.

#### Using pre-processors

For more browser support, you can use pre-processors like `SASS` or `LESS`, with the same technique.

The main idea is to not use plain color codes in your main CSS file(s), but use variables that load the colors you defined in you color scheme.

Have a great day.
Cheers